# The name 'Buffer' does not exist in the current scope

Tags: node.js, typescript

a.ts

```
///<reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
class A {
  constructor(public b: Buffer) {
  }
}
```

tsc a.ts

(3,24): The name 'Buffer' does not exist in the current scope

Comment: and now what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have to have the type be "NodeBuffer" rather than "Buffer".

```
///<reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
class A {
    constructor(public b: NodeBuffer) {
    }
}
```